# In @SpringBootApplication package scan not working

Tags: maven, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've a spring boot application which uses other modules using maven dependency.

All the modules have same package structure.

For example: `com.ams.web.model`, `com.ams.web.repository`, `com.ams.web.service` and `com.ams.web.websocket`.

And I've `com.ams.web` for my main module config of springbootapplication with main method. But when I try to start the server, it fails with autowiring issues. This indicates that the application is unable to scan the package from the sub modules. [All the required classes have either `@Service` or `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation which should enable them for scanning]

How does the pacakge scan works by default in springboot application which has maven dependecy on other modules? How do I enable packge scan of other modules from my spring application.

Code:

```
package com.ams.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import com.ams.web.filters.AllRequestFilter;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.ams.web"})
public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
       context.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

       PropertyConfigurator.configure(loadLog4jProperties(context));
       String profile = loadProperties.getProperty("env.name", "app");

       System.out.println("Env Profile : " + profile);

        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = context.getEnvironment();
    environment.setActiveProfiles(profile);

        context.setServletContext(servletContext);


        servletContext.addFilter("AllRequestFilter", new AllRequestFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        servletContext.addFilter("amsSpringAllRequestFilter", new AmsSpringAllRequestFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
```

UrlList:

```
package com.ams.web.repository;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ams.web.environment.All;

@All
@Component
public class UrlList {
```

My custom Annotation in a different module:

```
package com.ams.web.environment;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile( "app", "mock", "test")
@Component
public @interface All {}
```

Comment: Follow the advice of the Spring team and put the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` in a top level package that covers all packages, in your case `com.ams.web`. Only adding `@ComponentScan` will only enable parts of the auto configuration (especially if you use things like Spring Data JPA etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but as you can see in my question, I've my "@SpringBootApplication" class in the same package. I don't have individual "@ComponentScan".

Comment: No I cannot see that clearly in your question, there is vague mention of a package but not if the class is there or if it is in the `@SpringBootApplicaiton` annotation etc. So instead of describing things, add the error, add some code (including the `package ...` statements please) .

Comment: Added the code for more clarification.

Comment: And you are destroying the functioning of the `SpringBootServletInitializer` and wonder why it isn't working? Don't override the `onStartup` method.  The `WebInitializer` itself is in the `com.ams.web` package so remove the `scanBasePackages`). The fact that you are messing around with an overriden `onStartup` method means you are trying to work around Spring Boot instead of using Spring Boot, work with the framework instead of around it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried without scanBasePackages it didn't work. Also i needed to register filters and load environment properties. Hence overriding onStartup(). If you have alternative solution, do let me know.

Comment: Spring Boot registers the filters for you (just define them as `@Bean` in your configuration) as well as reading the environment properties (see https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config). All of that is supported out-of-the-box. As stated work with the framework instead of around the framework.

Comment: Okay. Do you think removing the override of onStartup will resolve this Autowiring issue of my repositories and services?

Comment: Yes it will as that will enable the default Spring Boot behavior which you have now disabled. So basically you are running without Spring Boot at the moment.

Comment: I tried by not overriding the onStartUp. I got the below error. "Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ams.web.repository.UrlList' in your configuration."

Comment: Apparently `UrlList` isn't a comment that is being scanned.

Comment: I've pasted the code for UrlList

Comment: Have you enabled the profile? You probably need something like `spring.profiles.active=${env.name}` in your `application.properties`. Or specify the `spring.profiles.active` instead of `env.name`.

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked with setting the profile while starting the server. I use to do it in onStartUp method which I've removed now.